# How to save user inputted value in TextBox?

Tags: vb.net

I have a Textbox that I want to be saved after it is closed, and then given to another computer.

```
Public Class Form1
        Dim textBoxes() As TextBox

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    textBoxes = New TextBox() {TextBox2}

    With My.Settings
        If .TextBoxValues Is Nothing Then .TextBoxValues = New System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
        For i = 0 To textBoxes.Length - 1
            If .TextBoxValues.Count <= i Then .TextBoxValues.Add("")
            textBoxes(i).Text = .TextBoxValues(i)
        Next
    End With
```

In Settings I have a Setting called TextBoxValues
system.collections.specialized.stringcollection
  And then, this works with Scope User, but it doesn't save if the application is moved, or given to another computer. So I have to change the Scope to Application. But when I turn it to Application I get this Error:
Property 'TextBoxValues' is 'ReadOnly'. 
for

```
.TextBoxValues = New System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must save in a txt file, XML or somethig ..
 because in other way how you keep dtat typed data ? :)